# SYNTAX ERROR (change nameclass on assignment) in APL

Tags: syntax-error, variable-assignment, assign, apl, dyalog

When I try to assign to a name in Dyalog APL, I get one of these error messages:

- `SYNTAX ERROR: Can't change nameclass on assignment`
- `SYNTAX ERROR: Invalid modified assignment, or an attempt was made to change nameclass on assignment`

What exactly does it mean to "change nameclass on assignment", why isn't it allowed, and how can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What exactly does it mean to "change nameclass on assignment"?

APL distinguishes between syntactic roles, and each role is identified by a number. The `⎕NC` function takes one or more names, and returns their [Name Class](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Primitive%20Functions/Assignment.htm), for example 2 for variable and 3 for function, 4 for operator, and 9 for ref.

As per the [assignment documentation](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Primitive%20Functions/Assignment.htm):

> ##### Re-Assignment
>
> A name that already exists may be assigned a new value if the assignment will not alter its name class, or will change it from 2 to 9 or vice versa. The table of permitted re-assignments is as follows:
>
> |  | Ref | Variable | Function | Operator |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Ref | Yes | Yes |  |  |
> | Variable | Yes | Yes |  |  |
> | Function |  |  | Yes | Yes |
> | Operator |  |  | Yes | Yes |

#### Why isn't it allowed?

The prohibition against certain re-assignments is necessary to disambiguate when an [augmented assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment) is performed, or when the [value of an assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Value_of_an_assignment) is used (whatever is on the right of the assignment arrow is returned as result). For example:

```
      Plus←+
      a←100
      a Plus←10
      a
110
      Double←{2×⍵}
      Double b←10
20
```

Without this restriction, it would be impossible to distinguish these cases from [parallel assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Parallel_assignment):

```
      c d←10
      c
10
      d
10
```

#### How can I work around this issue?

Reusing a name for something entirely different is probably a bad idea in production code, and adoption of a strict naming convention (e.g. [mine](https://abrudz.github.io/style#nc)) is recommended. However, when experimenting in an interactive session (REPL), simply removing the definition of an existing name, opens up its usage for all purposes. The `⎕EX` (expunge) system function and the `)ERASE` system command both do this:

```
      a←10
      a←+
SYNTAX ERROR: Can't change nameclass on assignment
      a←+
       ∧
      ⎕EX'a'
      a←+
      a←10
SYNTAX ERROR: Invalid modified assignment, or an attempt was made to change nameclass on assignment
      a←10
      ∧
      )erase a
      a←10
```